# I cannot use SPI to communicate TI ADS1299 with MSP432P401R in CCS

Tags: spi

MSP432P401R is master
ADS1299 is slave
How to write SPI code, let MSP432P401R read data of ADS1299
The program I am using CCS(Code Composer Studio)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the datasheet. They have clearly mentioned how to communicate in SPI in the datasheet

[image]

Visit http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1299.pdf

But ads1299 is a very sensitive chip. So I am not recommending to write it yourself. The OpenBCI has written a c++ library for ads1299. I suggest to use it.

the header file and the c++ file can be found here

https://github.com/OpenBCI/OpenBCI_8bit/tree/master/OpenBCI_8bit_Library/OpenBCI_8